# How do you put {0,0} into an array and able to change it when a if statement is met

Tags: java, arrays, coordinates, element

My plan is to create an array with only two values, which is {0,0} because I want to change its value in order to simulate how the coordinate moves. 
I want to move the coordinate up to (0,1) when a random number is assigned to x,

let's say I have a line of if loop,

```java
if(x=0){ //I would change the value from {0,0} to {0,1} }
```

I tried to write the code in this way,

```java
public static int x = 0;
public static int y = 0;
public static void randomWalk(int [] moving_point) {
    int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4);
    if(r == 0) {
        moving_point[x,y] = moving_point[x,y+1];
    }
}
```

but it is not correct,

is this a possible thing to do? and how? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innermost code must be changed to:

`moving_point[1] = moving_point[1] + 1;`

The `1` gives you the index of the 'y' position in your moving_point array, but will not modify your fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int x = 0;
public static int y = 0;
public static void randomWalk(int [] moving_point) {
    int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4);
    if(r == 0) {
        moving_point[x,y] = moving_point[x,++y];   
    }
}
```

I would suggest to use Pre-Increment(`++x`) in this scenario. `Pre-increment` means that the variable is incremented BEFORE it's evaluated in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
moving_point[1]++;
```

inside the for.

I suggest you not to pass an array to the function since the method can't assume its length. You can either pass two ints or pass a class, there are severals already implemented: [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

The arguably 'correcter' way to represent a Coordinate in Java is to create a Coordinate class:

```
public class Coordinate {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void moveUp(int distance) {
        y += distance;
    }
    public void moveDown(int distance) {
        y -= distance;
    }
    public void moveLeft(int distance) {
        x -=distance;
    }
    public void moveRight(int distance) {
        x += distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%d,%d}", x, y);
    }

}

public static void randomWalk(Coordinate point) {
    int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4);
    if(r == 0) {
        point.moveUp(1);
    }
}
```

This allows you to succinctly represent multiple Coordinates in your software, as well as allowing you to write some very intuitive methods, such as the `moveUp/Down/Left/Right` in the above example.

Another good reason for doing this is that there are no constraints on your array, so someone could inadvertently add a third, fourth or fifth value, which clearly wouldn't make sense. Using a separate class makes the code more self-documenting.

Back to the example, you can now run:

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(0, 0);
System.out.println(c); // prints "{0,0}"
randomWalk(c);
System.out.println(c); // prints "{0,1}" IF you were lucky to get a random 0...
```

---

NB:
Here, Coordinate space is interpreted as like on a graph in school, increasing x to the right and increasing y going up. On computer screens the y-space is usually flipped (the origin is the top left of the screen), so as an exercise consider how you might correct that. (Hint, it only involves changing`moveUp()` and `moveDown()`)

---

Edit:
Following your comment, to be able to record the path, you'll probably want to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of `ArrayList` (efficiency of lookups while keeping the ordering) and make `Coordinate` immutable by returning a new instance from each `moveX` operation. You will also need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```
public class Coordinate {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Coordinate moveUp(int distance) {
        return new Coordinate(x, y+distance);
    }
    public Coordinate moveDown(int distance) {
        return new Coordinate(x, y-distance);
    }
    public Coordinate moveLeft(int distance) {
        return new Coordinate(x-distance, y);
    }
    public Coordinate moveRight(int distance) {
        return new Coordinate(x+distance, y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%d,%d}", x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //we need to do something a bit more clever than "x+y", otherwise {1,0} might end up with the same hash as {0,1}
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) return true;
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Coordinate other = (Coordinate)obj;
        if(x != other.x) return false;
        if(y != other.y) return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class Walker {
    private LinkedHashSet<Coordinate> path = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private Coordinate last;
    public Walker(Coordinate startingPoint) {
         path.add(startingPoint);
         last = startingPoint;
    }

    public Set<Coordinate> getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void randomWalk() {
        int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4);
        if(r == 0) {
            Coordinate nextStep = last.moveUp(1);
            if(path.add(nextStep)) {
                //Set returns "true" if the item was added, "false" otherwise.
                last = nextStep;
            } else {
                //So if not added, we've already been there. 
                //take alternative action, retry, whatever...
            }
        }
    }
}

Walker w = new Walker(new Coordinate(0,0));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    w.randomWalk();
}
System.out.println(w.getPath());
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, my plan is also to save the path or the coordinates to an ArrayList so whenever I want to move to the next point I will be able to check whether there is a duplicate coordinate saved in the ArrayList or not, then I can move to another point and no turning back, just like how a self-avoiding random walk would work.

Is it more possible to be done in your way of setting up coordinates or my way setting up the coordinates?

Comment: I have added to my answer. Using an array can be done, but you couldn't use the built-in efficiency of `LinkedHashSet` in conjunction with `equals` and `hashCode`, as you couldn't override them on your array, and therefore would be limited to Object equality, i.e. arrays containing the same numbers wouldn't be equal unless they were the exact same instance. Put another way: Using arrays would be far less readable, to the point of not being "Object Oriented".